# What is this weed with 5 serrated edge whorl and runners?

Tags: identification

I'd like to know what is this is and whether there is any problem with encouraging it as a lawn alternative which is what it's naturally done in my neglected London back garden. /Users/AmandaCarter/Library/Containers/com.apple.mail/Data/Library/Mail Downloads/94B5A893-50F0-43FE-9D22-192CD7E74720/IMG_0461.JPG

Comment: Hi Amanda, first off, welcome to the forum. :)  If you don't mind, please try to add the image again.

Comment: Yes please upload again, image is not accessible in its current format

Comment: The best alternative for a lawn I have found is crushed compacted gravel.